# Close down menu on mobile upon link click

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the menu on mobile to close down when the user clicks a link.

See here : https://siteweb.synergieetvitalite.com/monportfolio/heidi/

I am not certain how to change the javascript of the menu to get the right behaviour.

```
    setupToggleButton($scope) {
    if (this.isMobileMenu($scope)) {
        $scope.$toggle = $scope.find('.opalelementor-menu-toggle');
        var style =  $scope.$toggle.data('style') ;
        var effect =  $scope.$toggle.data('effect') 

        if( style == 'poup' ){  
            $scope.$toggle.magnificPopup({
                type        : 'inline',
                mainClass: 'mfp-with-fade',
                removalDelay: 500,
                overflowY   : 'hidden',
                callbacks   : {
                    beforeOpen: function () {  
                        this.st.mainClass = effect;
                    },
                    close: function () {
                         $scope.$toggle.removeClass('opalelementor-active');
                    }
                },
                midClick    : true
            });

        } else {
            $scope.$toggle.on('click', () => { 
                this.$dropdownMenu = $scope.find('.opalelementor-nav-menu--dropdown.opalelementor-nav-menu__container');
                $scope.$toggle.toggleClass('opalelementor-active');
                this.toggleMenu($scope, $scope.$toggle.hasClass('opalelementor-active'));
                return false; 
            });
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is lacking some information. 1) Can you post the relevant html that you are using your script with? 2) do you get any JavaScript errors in your console?  3) What is the exact problem you are facing? Is your button element not found with getElementById() ? or isn't your click handler code executed? Or is your code executed but the style of your menu isn't changed? Also 4) your code is missing some closing }. And 5) what is the significance of the target checks? You're applying your  click handler on an html element by ID, for which there can be only 1 on the page

Comment: right, my button element was not found... because it changes each time you load the page it seems

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured this out...

it works by adding this code :

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($){$('body').on('click','.opalelementor-nav-menu--dropdown.opalelementor-nav-menu__container a',function(){  $(".opalelementor-menu-toggle").click();
});
  var body = $( 'body' );
});
</script>
```